# Validating delete in Hbase Java

Tags: java, api, hbase

I am trying to validate the deletion of the column family in Java but I am confused how to validate whether it is deleted or not.
Here's my code:

```
Table table = connection.getTable(Tablename.valueof("test:table");
Delete del = new Delete(Bytes.getBytes("row1");
del.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("colFam2");
table.delete(delete);
Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("row1"));
Result result = table.get(g);
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. `table.delete` returns void, so if you want to check if a row was deleted, running `table.get` seems to be a valid way to me

Comment: Agreed, and even though the `delete` method returns void, any failures will throw an exception.